# Bold brackets in equation environment

Tags: equations, matrices, brackets

I want to write an equation with bold extended brackets.

For example:

```
\begin{equation}
x_k = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & T_s & \displaystyle \dfrac{T_s^2}{2} \\ 0 & 1 & T_s \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right] x_{k-1} + \xi 
\end{equation}
```

But I can't obtain bold brackets ([ and ]).

Thank you for helping.

Comment: @egreg I would have suggested to reopen the question, but I see it has already been done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the purpose is, but…

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{cmexb}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmexb}{b}{n}{<->cmexb10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{boldoperators}{OT1}{\familydefault}{b}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{boldlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmexb}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrackbold}{\mathopen} {boldoperators}{"5B}{boldlargesymbols}{"02}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrackbold}{\mathclose}{boldoperators}{"5D}{boldlargesymbols}{"03}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{boldbmatrix}{\left\lbrackbold\env@matrix}{\endmatrix\right\rbrackbold}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{boldbmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{boldbmatrix}
\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you prefer this type of bold big braces or more bigger than `\Bigg`? Here there is a minimal working example with a specific screenshot.

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{txex}{b}{n} %%%% >--- see the link https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=27058
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x_k = \bm{\Bigg[}\begin{matrix} 1 & T_s & \frac{T_s^2}{2} \\ 0 & 1 & T_{s} \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\bm{\Bigg]} x_{k-1} + \xi 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you use `scalerel` package created by [@Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes) with the option `scaleobj` you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{txex}{b}{n} 
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x_k = \scaleobj{1.2}{\bm{\Bigg[}}\begin{matrix} 1 & T_s & T_s^2/2 \\ 0 & 1 & T_{s} \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\scaleobj{1.2}{\bm{\Bigg]}}\,x_{k-1} + \xi 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```